# How to multiply two data frame column by column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to similarity between columns within the one data frame. The expected result is the same as the correlation matrix output, but the calculation function is different(I wrote my self calc function). So the calc function should get `calc_func(column1, column2)`. The idea is to get similarities between columns. row size is not important. as an Output I expect (937,937) matrix.

Sample data

```
                  0011         0012          0013      0014       0015        0019          0111        0112        0121          0122       0123       0125       0129          0161       0168          0172       0174      0175       0176       0221        0222       0223       0224        0230       0241       0242          0243       0249       0251       0252          0341        0342       0344       0345       0351        0352       0353        0361       0362        0363        0371       0372          0411          0412       0421        0422       0423       0430        0441          0449       0452        0453        0459       0461          0471          0472       0481        0482       0483      0484       0485       0541        0542          0544       0545       0546       0547        0548          0561       0564          0566       0567       0571       0572        0573          0574          0575         0576       0577       0579       0581          0583  \
Reporter ISO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
AFG            0.149474     0.699753  0.000000e+00  0.000000   0.000000    6.084805  0.000000e+00    0.013655    0.123035  0.000000e+00   0.000000   0.011263   0.000000  0.000000e+00   0.000000  0.000000e+00   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000    0.000000   0.040835   0.009775    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  1.902343e-04   0.003110   0.000000   0.000000  9.900480e-04    0.000382   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000    0.000000   0.000000    0.000000   0.002613    0.002373    0.000184   0.000000  0.000000e+00  5.570409e-04   0.000000    0.001367   0.023009   1.074305    0.000000  4.309246e-04   2.267049    0.135528    6.845710   0.000172  4.785010e-02  5.620574e-04   0.015391    0.000000   0.000000  0.008071   0.000000   0.602458   56.772035  4.902713e+01  11.542497   0.175537   0.000000    8.314311  6.899700e-01   0.009341  0.000000e+00   0.118446   0.465433   0.634222    0.008141  4.406345e+01  1.806608e+02  1457.266474  37.572639  16.111153   0.278868  5.828552e-01   
AGO            0.000233     0.000000  2.169950e-05  0.000436   0.000021    0.206904  1.850937e-05    0.001081    0.000054  4.163925e-04   0.000437   0.000348   0.000059  1.287730e-04   0.000289  9.425705e-04   0.000140  0.002698   0.000444   0.000116    0.002252   0.000614   0.000295    0.000481   0.000003   0.000008  0.000000e+00   0.000142   0.000742   0.002136  3.700936e-01    1.594887   0.024370   0.000002   0.039695    0.146148   0.000020    0.267286   0.866269    0.036852    0.000384   0.046401  4.496454e-06  0.000000e+00   0.000834    0.016216   0.001110   0.000000    0.000065  7.354149e-04   0.000061    0.004332    0.000039   0.239055  2.501597e-01  3.830196e-04   0.000546    0.008450   0.015806  0.001086   0.002724   0.009187    0.005919  3.321169e-04   0.002146   0.000693   0.001050    0.006553  2.621612e-03   0.017289  8.732829e-05   0.000309   0.000343   0.000303    0.053893  5.683467e-04  6.637084e-05     0.000005   0.000036   0.001527   0.000022  1.886017e-07   
ALB            0.004472     0.093826  0.000000e+00  0.000000   0.000000    4.959089  5.096002e-02    0.000000    0.000000  2.111634e-03   0.000487   0.003162  17.984117  1.681137e-02   0.000287  3.287117e-02   0.001309  0.001702   0.000093   0.005981    0.000027   0.004139   0.007258    0.000442   0.000000   0.122049  0.000000e+00   0.028040   1.376963   0.109314  2.201071e+00    0.646953   0.427123   0.055488  37.156633   24.666195   0.000416    0.452249   0.423161    1.855032    9.630443  16.673592  2.321445e-03  5.822343e-03   0.264946    0.000000   0.001616   0.000000    0.067036  1.468721e-03   0.000867    0.000000    0.000000   0.051276  3.280251e-02  1.379145e-02   0.026767    0.000000   0.315969  0.634852   0.004309   0.343613    0.302088  2.262782e+01   4.408535   0.013666   1.185906    1.818876  1.082149e+00   0.031302  5.695562e-03   3.008238   1.286605   0.064267    0.004062  1.028946e+00  5.242426e-02     2.020501   0.595951   1.282575   0.059749  8.487325e-01
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really match your title.  Please show us an example of what you're after.  Do you want a new column with the result of your calculation?  Are you looking for a correlation of one row against itself?  One row against another row?  Correlation happens between two vectors, so having 3 rows is confusing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your response. I clearly stated that between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using exactly the [example in the docs for `df.corr()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

> ```
> def histogram_intersection(a, b):
>      v = np.minimum(a, b).sum().round(decimals=1)
>      return v
>
> df = pd.DataFrame([(.2, .3), (.0, .6), (.6, .0), (.2, .1)],
>                   columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
>
> df.corr(method=histogram_intersection)
> # output:
>      dogs  cats
> dogs   1.0   0.3
> cats   0.3   1.0
> ```

So just pass your function in as the `method` parameter:

```py
df.corr(method=calc_func)
```